# How to make a library from .pas files and use it in a C++Builder project targeting Android?

Tags: android, delphi, static-libraries, c++builder

I'm trying to use a `.a` library in an Android project, made using C++Builder 11.2 from a collection of Delphi `.pas` files.

When I try to run the project, the IDE doesn't start the debug mode, and the device shows a black screen as a clear failure of the application. If I try again then the IDE shows the following error:

> Can't bind address: Address already use. Exiting.

If I remove that `.a` library from the project, the linker fails with undefined references to the library files.

Those `.pas` files conform the ZXing.Delphi library, and I want to use them to make a static library with C++Builder called `libZXing.a` and add it to my project targeting Android.

I already made the `libZXing.a` library using C++Builder static library project and build it for Android. Then I added it to my C++Builder project application for Android. I also added to the include path all the `.hpp` files the IDE generated from the `.pas` files when I build them as part of the `libZXing.a`.

My application for Android includes a `.pas` unit where I'm using a procedure of the ZXing.Delphi library, so I followed the recommendations about how to call Delphi code from C++Builder. The application for Android compiles successfully, but fails when try to run as described before.

Is it possible to make that `libZXing.a` library in the way I'm trying to do? Is there something wrong or missing on my approach to call Delphi code from C++Builder?

Here is the `.pas` unit included in my application for Android, where I'm using a procedure of the `libZXing.a` library:

```pascal
unit uZXing;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants, System.Math.Vectors, System.Actions, System.Threading, System.Permissions,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.Objects, FMX.StdCtrls, FMX.Media, FMX.Platform, FMX.MultiView, FMX.ListView.Types,
  FMX.ListView, FMX.Layouts, FMX.ActnList, FMX.TabControl, FMX.ListBox, FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.ScrollBox, FMX.Memo, FMX.Controls3D, FMX.Memo.Types,
  ZXing.BarcodeFormat, ZXing.ReadResult, ZXing.ScanManager;

type
  IMyDelphiInterface = interface
    procedure ParseImage(fScanInProgress: Boolean; fScanBitmap: TBitmap; lblScanStatus: TLabel; strList: TStringList);
  end;

  function ZXing_DelphiInstance() : IMyDelphiInterface;

implementation

type
  TDelphiClassImplementingInterface = class(TInterfacedObject, IMyDelphiInterface)
    public
    procedure ParseImage(fScanInProgress: Boolean; fScanBitmap: TBitmap; lblScanStatus: TLabel; strList: TStringList);
  end;

function ZXing_DelphiInstance() : IMyDelphiInterface;
begin
  Result := TDelphiClassImplementingInterface.Create;
end;

procedure TDelphiClassImplementingInterface.ParseImage(fScanInProgress: Boolean;
  fScanBitmap: TBitmap; lblScanStatus: TLabel; strList: TStringList);
begin
  TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
    procedure
    var
      ReadResult: TReadResult;
      ScanManager: TScanManager;
    begin
      fScanInProgress := True;
      ScanManager := TScanManager.Create(TBarcodeFormat.Auto, nil);
      try
        try
          ReadResult := ScanManager.Scan(fScanBitmap);
        except
          on E: Exception do
          begin
            TThread.Synchronize(TThread.CurrentThread,
              procedure
              begin
                lblScanStatus.Text := E.Message;
              end);
            exit;
          end;
        end;
        TThread.Synchronize(TThread.CurrentThread,
          procedure
          begin
            if (Length(lblScanStatus.Text) > 10) then
            begin
              lblScanStatus.Text := '*';
            end;
            lblScanStatus.Text := lblScanStatus.Text + '*';
            if (ReadResult <> nil) then
            begin
              strList.Add(ReadResult.Text);
            end;
          end);
      finally
        if ReadResult <> nil then
          FreeAndNil(ReadResult);
        ScanManager.Free;
        fScanInProgress := false;
      end;
    end).Start();
end;

end.
```

And here is the approach to call Delphi code from C++Builder:

```cpp
_di_IMyDelphiInterface DI_ZXing { ZXing_DelphiInstance() };
TStringList *strList;

TThread::Synchronize(TThread::CurrentThread,
[this, DI_ZXing, strList]() {
    CameraComponent1->SampleBufferToBitmap(imgCamera->Bitmap, True);
    if(fScanInProgress)
        exit;
    fFrameTake++;
    if(fFrameTake % 4 != 0)
        exit;
    if(fScanBitmap)
        fScanBitmap->DisposeOf();
    fScanBitmap = new TBitmap;
    fScanBitmap->Assign(imgCamera->Bitmap);
    DI_ZXing->ParseImage(fScanInProgress, fScanBitmap, Form_TabbedTemplate->LabelCapachos_OBRScan, strList);
});
```

Comment: I'm a bit lost - what is the actual problem you are having?

Comment: Remy: aside from the fact that the app does not start, and shows a black screen? I'm curious as to why a separate library is needed at all, and why there's all the extra detail in the question, because unless a scan is happening immediately at startup, that code is not going to be executed.

Comment: Remy: the problem is that the application does start and works well without the 'libZXing.a' library and do not start when I add it. I have not experience on this matter, so I'm thinking that probably it is wrong to asume that I could just create the library grouping all .pas files on a C++ Builder static library, may be there is another piece of code that is necessary to allow it works on my Android application.